# Validate for a valid SQL string

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Is there a way (or existing library, not necessarily built into .NET) in C# that performs simple SQL string validation?

Scenario: Building update statement to reduce load on SQL load vs. individual statements. In case the string build does something "odd", like ending with a comma for instance, I'd like to be able to validate that the string is correct.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to validate the SQL statement??  Your scenario doesn't seem to shed any light.

Comment: Yeps, that's what I said hehe. I clarified the scenario though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to validate the SQL using SQL Server, you can do so by adding

```
SET PARSEONLY ON
```

before your script, and then

```
SET PARSEONLY OFF
```

after your script.

---

If you need to avoid going to the database, then maybe you can use the assemblies that [Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=BB3AD767-5F69-4DB9-B1C9-8F55759846ED&displaylang=en) includes (they have code that handles SQL parsing and script generation). If you don't have the database edition or team suite, you can download the trial version to get the assemblies.

[Here is a link](http://chadwickmiller.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!EA42395138308430!296.entry) I found where someone is using these assemblies.

Comment: Surely this still sends data off to SQL though for the validation? I am more looking for something to validate on the logic tier, not on the data tier.

Comment: Yes, but what could be more valid than using SQL Server to do the validation?  You could even use a local server to speed it up if you want.

Comment: I think that using a local SQL server for only validation is overkill to the nth degree. Right now, it still sends off to SQL and will return with an error if there's a problem. I want to skip the middle step and validate (at least to a decent degree) on the logic tier.

Comment: I added to my answer, a solution that might work. Check it out.

Comment: Have you seen my modified answer? I really think it's the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted it as it is something that can be done. I don't have access to TS DBE, but I know it will work.

Comment: You can download the trial version to get the assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

This third party component does a pretty good job of validating sql without going to the server. [SqlParser](http://www.sqlparser.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed that if you declare a new `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` object and set the `ConnectionString` field to a syntactically invalid connection string, it will throw exception, so this would be one way of checking.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection foo
        = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
foo.ConnectionString = "not a valid connection string"; //exception thrown here
```

Comment: As you already wrote, this works only for the ConnectionString, but not for the SQL statement itself.

Comment: oops, you're right.  He said "SQL String", not "SQL Connection String"