# Regular expression of simple boolean expression with parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write regular expression that should get only the following patterns:

`WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value'`

and patterns with multiple sub expressions like:

`WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value' OR WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value2' AND WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value3'`

`WordWihoutNumbers` must be at least two characters and without digits.

for example, those are valid string:

- Hardware.Make=’Lenovo’
- Hardware.Make=’Lenovo’ OR User.Sitecode=’PRC’

and those are not:

- Hardware.Make=’Lenovo’ OR => because there is nothing after the OR operator
- Hardware.Make=’Lenovo =>  ' missing
- Hardware Make=’Lenovo => . missing
- Hardware.Make’Lenovo' => = missing

I used RegexBuddy to write the following Regex string:

```
(?i)(\s)*[a-z][a-z]+(.[a-z][a-z]+)(\s)*=(\s)*'[a-z0-9]+'(\s)*((\s)*(AND|OR)(\s)*[a-z][a-z]+(.[a-z][a-z]+)(\s)*=(\s)*'[a-z0-9]+')*
```

When I tested it using RegexBuddy it worked fine but when I using it inside my C# code I'm always getting 'false' result.

What am I'm doing wrong?

This is what I did in my C# code:

```
string expression = "Hardware.Make=’Lenovo’ OR User.Sitecode=’PRC’";
Regex expressionFormat = new Regex(@"(?i)(\s)*[a-z][a-z]+(.[a-z][a-z]+)(\s)*=(\s)*'[a-z0-9]+'(\s)*((\s)*(AND|OR)(\s)*[a-z][a-z]+(.[a-z][a-z]+)(\s)*=(\s)*'[a-z0-9]+')*");
bool result = expressionFormat.IsMatch(expression );
```

and result parameter is always `false`

---

UPDATE: thanks to @nhahtdh for his comment, I used a `’` in my input checking instead of `'`
I need to add to this expression also parenthesis validation, for example:
((`WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value' OR WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value2') AND WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value3'`) is valid but

)`WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value' OR WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value2') AND WordWihoutNumbers.WordWihoutNumbers='value3'`) is invalid.

Is it possible to implement using Regex? do you have an idea?

---

Comment: Can you show how you include the regex in the C# code?

Comment: Probably you are not doubling (escaping) \? like \\s?

Comment: I added @ so I don't think that this is the reason

Comment: The problem is `’` and `'` are different code points.

Comment: @nhahtdh you are genius!!! I wasted 2 hr in trying to understand what is wrong with my expression and that was the problem. Feeling stupid :-(

Comment: For the updated question, you could use an sql parser, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442311/parsing-a-sql-string-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @nhahtdh that found my issue.

the problem was that `’` and `'` are different code points and that was the reason my regular expression didn't work (it was input problem).